# Problems with variable scope in example swap for powershell

Tags: function, powershell, variables, scope, swap

```
$global:value1
$global:value2
$global:value3

function initialize {
    $value1 = 100
    $value2 = 500
}

function subtract {
    $value3 = $value1 - $value2
    Write-Host $value3
}

function swap {
    Write-Host Before swap Value1: $value1 "& Value2: "$value2
    $value3 = $value1
    $value1 = $value2
    $value2 = $value3
    Write-Host After swap Value1: $value1 "& Value2: "$value2
}

function run-myscript {
    cls
    initialize
    subtract
    swap
    subtract
}
```

Output:

> -400
>   Before swap Value1: 100 & Value2:  500
>   After swap Value1: 500 & Value2:  100
>   -400

Please explain this behaviour why i get both values as -400, i should get once -400 and second time 400

Comment: Each of function `initialize`, `subtract'` and `swap` create new child scope, thus variable change in that child scope do not affect variables values in parent scope. P.S. Suggestion: put `$value1 = 'Not'; $value2 = 'initialized';` before `initialize`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Figured out that i have to call every time the vairable by its scope i.e global

```
$global:value1
$global:value2
$global:value3
function initialize
{
$global:value1 = 100
$global:value2 = 500
}
function subtract
{
$global:value3 = $global:value1 - $global:value2
Write-Host $global:value3
}
function swap
{
Write-Host Before swap Value1: $value1 "& Value2: "$value2
$global:value3 = $global:value1
$global:value1 = $global:value2
$global:value2 = $global:value3
Write-Host After swap Value1: $value1 "& Value2: "$value2
}

function run-myscript
{
cls
initialize
subtract
swap
subtract
}
```

Comment: While this _does_ solve your current problem, this is a terrible practice. Don't write to variable outside your function unless strictly necessary. Pass parameter arguments to your functions and return output if necessary. Also, you can swap variables in a single assignment statement, like so: `$a,$b = $b,$a`

Comment: If you use the other languages concept like c, c++, java, C# then its different in powershell i believe, i may be wrong. There could be some other way to do this maybe.

Comment: No, in C++, Java and C# class methods, reused variable names not defined in methods' own scope will be translated to property names of the containing class by the compiler. This doesn't happen in PowerShell because a script is not itself a class. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You might read global values that are created outside your function but if you set a value inside a function they will be newly created within the local scope (unless you explicitly refer to the global with `$Global:...`).
So, if you set `$value1 = $value2` within your `swap` function you have two `$value1` values: one local `$Local:Value1` and one global: `$Global:Value1`.
Anyway, it is in general, it is not a good practice to manipulate global variables from within a function. Normally, you should input (pipe or arguments) and output (pipe) the concerned variables.
And if you do so, you will probably see the light and come to the conclusion that a swap 'function' already exists:

```
$Value1, $Value2 = $Value2, $Value1
```